# Default value for a function parameter of type Class?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to have a default value for a function parameter of type Class ?

Something like this

```
public sub MyMethod(A as integer, optional B as integer = 0, optional Control as Control = new TextEdit)
End Sub
```

I tried this but it gives an error : a constant expression is required

Any ideas please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional values must be viable literals. In the case of reference-types (except for `string`, which has different rules), this means: `null` (`Nothing`), or (identically) `default(TheType)` (whatever that is in VB). That's all.